# Control WebOS SmartTV with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, webos

I'm coding a universal controller that controls all smart devices in the house my script runs correctly but show's nothing`

```
##this is a universal controller
#1_controlling LG Webos smart tv
import os
from pylgtv import WebOsClient
import sys
import logging
class Device:
    counter=0
    def __init__(self,ip,name):
        self.ip=(ip)
        self.name=(name)
        Device.counter += 1
smarttv=Device('192.168.0.105','Smart')

class tv(Device):
    #launching an application
    def launch_app(self):
        logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stdout, level=logging.INFO)

        try:
            webos_client = WebOsClient(self)
            webos_client.launch_app('com.webos.app.music')

            for app in webos_client.get_apps():
                print(app)
        except:
            print("Error connecting to TV")
```

Comment: Your class `tv` is never used. And your indentation is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

`tv` should be capitalized since it is a class name

And it is a type of `Device`, so you can use that instead, and you'll need to call `launch_app()`, which is only available on an instance of that class, not a `Device`, so you should assign that to a variable.

You might want to double check what actual objects that `WebOsClient` accepts as parameters, too. The documentation says it's a IP string, not a `tv` object

```
class SmartTV(Device):
    #launching an application
    def launch_app(self, app):
        try:
            webos_client = WebOsClient(self.ip)
            webos_client.launch_app(app)

            for app in webos_client.get_apps():
                print(app)

smarttv = SmartTV('192.168.0.105','Smart')
smarttv.launch_app('com.webos.app.music')  # You're missing this
```

Comment: Sorry, can't test it, I don't have a WebOS device.